# PHP Twig Error: Object of class __TwigTemplate_XYZ could not be converted to string

Tags: php, twig, template-engine

Hey and good morning :).

I'll start with the error message and explain afterwards what I've tried and did:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class __TwigTemplate_[64chars] could not be converted to string in /someFolder/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php on line 139
```

The full error message as Image:

[The PHP Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztiaw.png)

The call stack as Text:

```
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0001  123400  {main}( )   ../handleOOP.php:0
2   0.0107  1269656 OOPHandler::runPage( )  ../handleOOP.php:7
3   0.0107  1269768 AnweisungEingeben->stepkontrolle( ) ../OOPHandler.php:62
4   0.0108  1271536 AnweisungEingeben->ausgabe( )   ../AnweisungEingeben.php:77
5   0.0383  1669484 Twig_Environment->render( ) ../AnweisungEingeben.php:442
6   0.0383  1669484 Twig_Environment->loadTemplate( )   ../Environment.php:347
7   0.0383  1669512 Twig_Environment->getTemplateClass( )   ../Environment.php:378
8   0.0384  1669512 Twig_Loader_Filesystem->getCacheKey( )  ../Environment.php:312
```

In the `AnweisungEingeben.php` I have the following code fragment:

```
include_once "../lib/Twig/Autoloader.php";
Twig_Autoloader::register();
$template_dirs = array(
        $root.'templates/web/anweisungen',
        [...]
);
$twig_loader = new Twig_Loader_Filesystem($template_dirs);
$twig = new Twig_Environment($twig_loader, array("debug" => true));
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('Anweisung_Base.phtml');
$wech = $twig->render($template); // line 442 from AnweisungEingeben.php
```

I already tried:

- If the paths are correct (via scandir("path"))
- If Twig gets loaded
- Minimal Code like

  ```
  $loader = new Twig_Loader_Array(array('index.html' => 'Hello World!'));
  $twig = new Twig_Environment($loader);
  echo $twig->render('index.html');
  ```

Unfortunately everything results in the same.

The strange thing is, that the exact same code is working flawlessly in a minimal project.

I know it's very chaotic, but the project is existing and growing now for about ~20 years and this twig approach is my try to start(!) separating the logic from the html code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mixing methods up, you are trying to pass a `Twig_Template` to the `Twig_Environment`'s render method, while this method actually expect the path to the template as it's first [parameter](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/api/master/Twig_Environment.html#method_render)

So either do :

```
$template = $twig->loadTemplate('Anweisung_Base.phtml');
echo $template->render();
```

Or

```
echo $twig->render('Anweisung_Base.phtml');
```